# Firebase .htaccess to json

Tags: php, firebase, .htaccess, firebase-hosting

I searched and found out .htaccess does not work in firebase only firebase.json
i want to make firebase.json to read .html files to php like this in .htaccess

```
[Apache2 @ Ubuntu/Debian: use this directive]

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
Or, from comment below:

AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
If your are running PHP as CGI (probably not the case), you should write instead:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Hosting doesn't have support for evaluating PHP code.  In fact, it doesn't directly support *any* backend code execution.

Your options for running backend code through Firebase Hosting is limited to [integrations with Cloud Functions and Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/serverless-overview).  If you must run PHP, then Cloud Run is your only option, and it will be a fair amount of work to get that solution fully configured and running.